# How does return function return a value to If statement?

Tags: c, return, function-calls

How is value 1 passed to the if statement in main function and how does the return function work with a recursive call in it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 int identicalTrees(struct node* a, struct node* b)
  {
if (a==NULL && b==NULL)
    return 1;

if (a!=NULL && b!=NULL)
{
    return
    (
        a->data == b->data &&
        identicalTrees(a->left, b->left) &&
        identicalTrees(a->right, b->right)
    );
}

return 0;
} 




 int main()
{
if(identicalTrees(root1, root2))
    printf("Both tree are identical.");
else
    printf("Trees are not identical.");

getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "return function"? `return` is not a function, it's a statement. And it returns a value to the caller because the language definition says so.

Comment: There are a few great videos that explain how recursion and the stack works on the Computerphile channel on youtube. You should watch them all. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv9NEXX1VHc, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrfcJCulsF4, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7t_pTlH9HwA, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ha78yWRDlE, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_NXz7I5dQc

Comment: You definetely want to read about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: Languages don't have "how", they only have "what". A `return` statement causes the flow of control to return from the current function to its caller. That's the "what" of the return statement. There's nothing more than that. Language *implementations* are concerned with "how".

Comment: @SpiderPig
Thanks for the videos.. i saw the first one n it cleared the doubt. 
it was the first condition check for null and returning 1 that i had not given much significance to. That was all :) Thank u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a method that has been declared to return a value is called, space is reserved on the stack for the return value each time that method is called. The **Return** statement places the value in that position on the stack and exits the method returning back to the code that called the method. The code that called the method retrieves the value put on the stack by the **Return** statement and uses it in the **If** statement.

In recursion, each successive call to a method has its own local stack variable space added to the top of the stack. When a method executes, the current top of stack pointer is decremented to "free" that method's stack space.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) and https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html for more detailed explanations.

Comment: That's one way of doing things. Returning via a register is probably more common.

Comment: @user3815757 see also [Wikipedia: Calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and its linked pages, e.g. [Wikipedia: x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) in cdecl chapter says _"..Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register.."_